# Theology of "Sisters of the Vast Black"

Tags: theology

I recently read "Sisters of the Vast Black" by Lina Rather, and rather enjoyed it.

But in the first half of the book, much was made-- or at least much was alluded to-- of a theological dilemma faced by the characters.  Perhaps I am looking for details that don't exist, but **what was the nature of the dilemma?**

> The most direct pertinent quote is:  "And what a theological tangle-- could a consecrated house be allowed to mate, be fertilized, give birth?  Or to seed another?  It was a hermaphrodite species-- many of its evolutionary cousins did not even require a mate.  No matter their decision, scholars back in Rome would debate it for years with increasingly esoteric justifications."

> I had the impression that whether the sisters did or did not allow their ship to mate, that they would be in some potentially theologically unpalatable position, but after finishing the book, I don't quite see either end of it.  If I squint hard enough, I can see that maybe they might be concerned about traveling in a ship that is no longer a virgin.  But that's a little unsatisfying because (A) it's such an on-the-nose Catholic concern that it's almost a satire and I'm sure that's not the author's intent, and (B) even if that's the case, I really don't understand the problem with *not* allowing it.

Answer (score 1):

The ship is *consecrated* -- that is, particularly dedicated to divine purposes.  To mate and have offspring would divert attention from those purposes.

Even inanimate objects that are consecrated are set aside for its new, special purposes.  The chalice used for Communion wine, for instance, is not something you drink out of for any other reason -- you use different cups for that.

Comment: If that's true (and I'm not convinced either way) it's really only half an answer, though.  What's the *theological* problem with just not allowing it?